# Can you set AM/PM in a GregorianCalendar date or is it something you can only get

Tags: java, time, gregorian-calendar

I had a look at the java api about GregorianCalendar and did not see any way of setting the am/pm
in its constructor. Can you set AM/PM in a GregorianCalendar date or is it something you can only get using a get method on the calendar. Does it handle all of this automatically. I am looking to take the am/pm and output it in my toString for a class which has a date object. I was going to use the get method on the calendar to achieve this. I understand the am/pm is an int that is 0 or 1.

Are all hours in the 24 hour format in Gregorian and does it automatically determines the am and pm?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

Gives the hour (0-12) for AM/PM format.

```
Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Gives the hour ranging from 0-24.

It does the conversion on its own. You don't need to tell it.

```
cal.set( Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM )
```

Will/Could *change* the point time this calendar object represents. (If it's 1:00PM you will have 1:00AM afterwards). This is true for `GregorianCalendar` (see comment to question by Peter Cetinski).

Btw/Hint imo you should use a `DateFormat` to ouput *your* preferred format.

Comment: Thanks MartinK,Much appreciated. I think I will use HOUR_OF_DAY as that sounds best for what I am doing. Thanks I will use the DateFormat. I have been using elsewhere in my code. Many Thanks. Thanks also Dilum and Peter

Comment: If you set AM PM that will also change the time millis.

Answer (score 6):

```
Calendar cal = new GreogorianCalendar();   
cal.set( Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM );
```

Comment: @Jigar/@Peter, do you know whether this is overridden if `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, ...)` is called *after* setting AM/PM?

Comment: Calls to set are for the most part cumulative. However, setting a field may affect other fields depending on the field and implementation of the Calendar.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Hi Dilum and Peter , I am not overriding the cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,...). At the moment I am not setting AM/PM either. I was able to set gregorian calender date as 24 hour but was now wondering how best to get the AM/PM to display in my toString methods. In my toString I print my getmethod which returns the date/time of the date object. It doesn't at the moment return am or pm.

Comment: Calendar.get(AM_PM) returns 0 or 1 for me, which is equal to Calendar.AM or Calendar.PM.

Answer (score 1):

Simply I did this :

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int am_pm = calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
    String ampm = "ampm";
    if (am_pm == 0) {
        ampm = "AM";
    } else {
        ampm = "PM";
    }
    jLabel1.setText(hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + ampm);
```